# Image thumbnail not generating properly using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I have writen a script in PHP to upload an image.

To the point, my goal is to upload and to send 2 images to the server, 1 the original and 1 is the thumbnail. My script works, but is not perfect. 
This is my script

```
<?php

     //this is script for get  data type file

      $acak        = rand(000000,999999);// for random
      $lokasi_file = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'];
      $nama_file   = $_FILES['fupload']['name'];

      $nama_file_acak = $acak.$nama_file;


      $ukuran_file = $_FILES['fupload']['size'];
      $tipe_file   = $_FILES['fupload']['type'];
      $direktori   = "fkendaraan/$nama_file_acak";

       $uplod = move_uploaded_file($lokasi_file,"$direktori"); //to move image from local to the server folder

     //to handle uplod thumbnail image
      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($direktori);

      $width = imagesx($img);
      $height = imagesy($img);

      $new_width = 200;

      $new_height = ($new_width/$width) * $height;

      $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );

      imagecopyresampled( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );

      //imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 200, 200, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );

      imagejpeg( $tmp_img, $direktori."thumb-".$nama_file_acak );

      imagedestroy($tmp_img);
      imagedestroy($direktori);
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------

```
//I have no Problem with query and database, it works fine
$sql = "";
$query = mysql_query($sql);


?>
```

This can run but not perfect because the result like this
[image]

[image]

Any one can help me to fix this? Im very nubie in php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
```

To this:

```
$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
```

Anyway I would recommend you to make use of some classes for these tasks such as: 
[Shiege Iseng Resize Class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/4571.html).

But of course, if you are trying to learn with this, that's ok :)